# Маршрут через несколько точек (маркеров) google maps java

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Всем привет!

Есть три маркера, через которые я пытаюсь проложить маршрут. Прокладываю маршрут от marker1 до marker2 и рисую polyline так:

```
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment
supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);

supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback()
{
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(56.31346627, 43.99070621)).zoom(17).bearing(0).tilt(0).build();
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
        googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);

        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(56.31346627, 43.99070621)).title("1").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)).snippet("Start"));

        Marker marker2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(56.31832176, 43.99624228)).title("2"));
        marker2.setSnippet("Второй");

        Marker marker3 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(56.32190348, 44.00031924)).title("3").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)).snippet("Finish"));

        com.google.maps.model.LatLng destinationMarker = new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(marker2.getPosition().latitude, marker2.getPosition().longitude);

        DirectionsApiRequest directions = new DirectionsApiRequest(geoApiContext).mode(TravelMode.WALKING);
        directions.origin(new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude));

        directions.destination(destinationMarker).setCallback(
                new PendingResult.Callback<DirectionsResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DirectionsResult result)
                    {
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() ->
                        {
                            for (DirectionsRoute route: result.routes)
                            {
                                List<com.google.maps.model.LatLng> decodedPath = PolylineEncoding.decode(route.overviewPolyline.getEncodedPath());
                                List<LatLng> newDecodedPath = new ArrayList<>();

                                for (com.google.maps.model.LatLng latLng: decodedPath)
                                {
                                    newDecodedPath.add(new LatLng(latLng.lat, latLng.lng));
                                }

                                Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(newDecodedPath));
                                polyline.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(FullMapActivity.this, R.color.colorBlack));
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable e)
                    {
                        Log.d("ROUTES", "onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });    
    }
});
```

Судя по докам для прокладывания маршрута через большее количество точек, нужно добавлять waypoints. В интернете нашёл только примеры добавления через json строку.
Подскажите, можно ли с DirectionsApiRequest проложить маршрут больше, чем через две точки?

Answer (score 1):

Методом тыка:

```
directions.waypoints(new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(marker2.getPosition().latitude, marker2.getPosition().longitude));
```